# Can I write generic extension method to run task?

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, task, extension-methods

I am calling this method: 
`Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<AppServiceResponse> AppServiceConnection.SendMessageAsync(ValueSet message)`

e.g. `await connection.SendMessageAsync(initialStatus);`

It shows an error: 'IAsyncOperation' does not contain a definition for "GetAwaiter" and no extension method "GetAwaiter" accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation'could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)

Then I change it to:

```
await Task.Run(() => connection.SendMessageAsync(initialStatus));
```

It got compiled.

My first question is why I cannot apply await to SendMessageAsync? What exactly does it mean "no definition for GetAwaiter"?

My second question is I also need to run other methods 
e.g. `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<AppServiceConnectionStatus> AppServiceConnection.OpenAsync()`

I write an extension method:

```
public static async void AsTask(this IAsyncOperation<AppServiceResponse> operation)
{
    await Task.Run(() => operation);
}
```

So I can call `connection.SendMessageAsync(initialStatus).AsTask();` But can I make the extension method generic so I can also call something like `connection.OpenAsync().AsTask();`

Comment: If you're going to use async/await, you _must_ return a `Task`, `Task<T>`, or `void`. `IAsyncOperation` is none of those... But there are already methods to convert to tasks in the [`WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Note this is not doing at all what you want it to. It is not awaiting the asynchronous operation. It is spawning a new thread that starts the async operation. The return value of the awaited Task is `IAsyncOperation<AppServiceResponse>`. You need to await that. As Jeff Mercado points out, there are already methods to convert these to tasks.

Comment: There are dangerous complexities with using Task.Run and you need to be incredibly careful how you do so.  See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Comment: For future reference: when you get an error like that, the first place to go is [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582011(v=vs.110).aspx). That page is the **very first** search result when I enter "iasyncoperation getawaiter" in the MSDN search page. And looking at that documentation page, you can see clearly what assembly the method is defined in (which you need to reference) and that it's an extension method (meaning you have to have the proper `using` directive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first question is why I cannot apply await to SendMessageAsync? What exactly does it mean "no definition for GetAwaiter"?

It means you're missing a reference to `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`.

> Then I change it to [use `Task.Run`] It got compiled.

Yes, but it won't work right. As mike commented, the return type of `Task.Run` here is `Task<IAsyncOperation<T>>`, which when awaited will *return* (not await) the actual `IAsyncOperation<T>`. So you're just *starting* the operation on a background thread and then awaiting for that operation to *start* - you're not awaiting for it to *complete*.

So, you shouldn't write an extension method. You shouldn't be using `Task.Run` at all here. Just add the missing reference, and you should be fine.